# prove that for every integer a it results gcd (a, a + 7) = gcd (a, 7)

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

how can I prove that for every integer $a$ results gcd ($a$, $a$ + 7) = gcd ($a$, 7) ?

Comment: If $x$ divides $a$ and $a+7$ then it divides their difference. On the other hand if $x$ divides $a$ and $7$ then it divides their sum.

Comment: thanks for the answer, is right but I would need an exam proof to prove that proposition.

Comment: If $\frac ax$ and $\frac {a+7}x$ are integers, what can you say about  $\frac {a+7}x-\frac ax$?

Comment: that are integers, but it doesn't answer the question that the gcd is the same, I mean.